# “One‘s wish is to do something” vs “One's wish is doing something”？

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, licensing

I can't see any difference between “His wish is to be a fighter jet pilot” and “His wish is being a fighter jet pilot”.

Answer (score 3):

The critical difference is that *wish*, both verb and noun, licenses infinitival complements but does not license gerund complements:

> <sup>ok</sup>I wish to go.
>   <sup>∗</sup>  I wish going.

"His wish is being ..." is not idiomatic.